# Conditionally change the *message* body font

Tags: outlook, automation, ms-office

I want to display the body font of emails from a certain sender in Courier New, or another fixed size font, because they contain ASCII tables. All other messages should use the Outlook 2010 default font.

Note that I don't care about the font used in the view pane (conditional formatting rules in View settings), or setting the default body font for all messages. I'm asking about an automatic, conditionally set font based on the sender email.

If it is not possible to automatically change the message font, what's the quickest way to switch between fonts, when reading and composing messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that out of the box, especially for a received message that is considered read-only.

For the messages that you compose, you can change the font style using something like the following:

```
'set Msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
set Msg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
set insp = Msg.GetInspector
set doc = insp.WordEditor
for each p in doc.Paragraphs
  set r = p.Range
  r.Font.Name = "Arial"
  r.Font.Size = 14
  r.Select
next
```

Comment: I'm sending the message from linux. I guess I'll have to send an html formatted message to change the font?

Comment: If you are the one who sends the message, the sky is the limit. You can simply use the `<pre>` tag to format your data in a fixed font.

Comment: plus all the HTML header envelope stuff? Or really just <pre font="Courier New">Hello</pre>?

Comment: Yes, just normal HTML, but surround the data that needs to be in the fixed style in the <pre>...</pre> tags.